# c# - How to implement simple workflow without WF?

Tags: c#, .net, workflow

I have not so complex but again not too simple workflow (defined by UML activity diagram) that I should implement in C#. I was wondering how to do it best without using Windows Workflow Foundation (with which I don't have previous experience and I don't have time to learn it from scratch right now). I am not sure if I should invest some time in learning some other simple workflow framework (any recommendations?) or should I just start implementing the workflow with my own classes.

I'd like to avoid complex classes and methods with too many if/else statements and make implementation as clear as possible. I am not sure which approach should I take so any hints are appreciated. For example, if someone gave you this workflow how would you go about implementing it? My workflow is a bit more complex but not too much.

[image]

Comment: Sounds like a state machine to me...

Answer (score 0):

You can model such a workflow using a state machine. Callbacks invoked on state transitions will allow custom processing in loosely coupled fashion.
But your task is not sufficiently specified.  For example, how do we transition from ReceiveOrder to AuthorizePayment? 
Please keep in mind that when you disregard WF you loose many features, that the infrastructure provides, such as persistance, predefined activities, easy external system exchange, workflow lifetime management, ability to visualize your workflow, etc.